# TensorFlow in Python for MNIST datasets('dict' object has no attribute 'train')

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried to use TensorFlow in Python for MNIST datasets as follows. Here I used the logistic regression model for neural networks for training. But there is an error report for my Code.

```
#import tensorflow
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets
mnist = tensorflow_datasets.load('mnist')

batch_size=100
n_batch=mnist.train.num_examples//batch_size

#PLACEHOLDER
#simple neural network
x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,784])
y=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,784])
prediction=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W)+b)
```

```
#Define loss function
loss=tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y-prediction))

#Gradient Descent
train_step=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0,2).minimize(loss)

init=tf.global_variables_initializer()

#Check accuracy of model
#These lines are used for converting one hot coding back to the original label form.
correct_prediction=tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1),tf.argmax(prediction,1))

#accuracy
accuracy=tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,tf.float32))
```

```
#training
#print predicted and true lables of first 10 test samples
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for epoch in range(21):
        for batch in range(n_batch):
            batch_xs,batch_ys=mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x:batch_xs,y:batch_ys})

            acc=sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict=({x:mnist.test.images,y:mnist.test.labels}))
    print("Iter"+str(epoch)+",Testing accuarcy"+str(acc))
```

However, the error report:

`AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'train'`

Comment: What is the output of `print(type(mnist))`? According to tensorflow datasets [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/overview#load_a_dataset) should be a [tf.data.Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mnist object is a dictionary with keys train and test. So, that's why you won't be able to access it like mnist.train

Access it like mnist['train'].

You can use len(mnist['train']) for getting num_examples

Comment: Sorry, I add my complete code.

Comment: Use this instead of tensorflow.load_datasets()

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data


mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data", one_hot=True)

Comment: Replace `mnist = tensorflow_datasets.load('mnist')`?

Comment: I used `input_data mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data", one_hot=True)
` but there is error 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax`